# Determine the real Fourier series for $f(t) = t^2$ with $t \in [0, 1[$ converging as fast as possible.

Tags: solution-verification, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Excuse my bad english.

```
Problem
```

> Determine the real Fourier series for $f(t) = t^2$ with $t \in  [0,1[$ converging as fast as possible.

```
My approach
```

> Firstly I periodically expanded so that we get slide mirror symmetry. The function I ended up with is given by $$g\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
> \left(t-0\right)^2&-1\le t\le \:1\\ 
> -\left[\left(t-2\right)^2-1\right]&1\le \:t\le\:\:3\\
> \end{cases}$$
>
> I also graphed the piecewise function on desmos [piecewise function $g(t)$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qacxl8dlnp)
>
> Secondly I started calculating the coëfficiënts $A_0$, $A_{2n}$, $B_{2n}$, $A_{2n-1}$, and $B_{2n-1}$
> since there's a slide mirror symmetry we get $A_0=A_{2n}=B_{2n}=0$ and $$A_{2n-1}=\frac{4}{T}\int _0^{\frac{T}{2}}g\left(t\right)\cos\left(n\omega t\right)dt$$ and
> $$B_{2n-1}=\frac{4}{T}\int _0^{\frac{T}{2}}g\left(t\right)\sin\left(n\omega t\right)dt$$

```
My questions
```

> $1$. Is this the best or fastest way to solve this problem or are the other (better) ways?

> $2$. Have I approached this problem correctly?